# SAS==>SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, sas-macro

I tried to launch a SAS query after a connection to an 'MVT' (FAMA) SQL Server database, I have a problem that I cannot apply the DELETE function to empty the TAB1 table (this table already exists in the MVT database which is connected to SQL Sserver, I have the following error:

note: on the other hand I was able to apply the DROP function to delete the table but that is not my objective, my objective is to delete the rows

```
libname MVT sqlsvr shema="dbo" datasrc=FAMA user=xx pwd=xx;
run;

proc sql;
delete from MVT.TAB1 ;
quit;



28         proc sql;
29         delete from MVT.TAB1;
ERROR: CLI execute error: [SAS][ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver][Microsoft SQL Server]A cursor with the name
       'SQL_CURF02A540A00000000' does not exist.
ERROR: ROLLBACK issued due to errors for data set MVT.TAB1.DATA.
NOTE: Deletes were rolled back by the DBMS software.
NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and will continue to check the syntax of statements.
30         run;
NOTE: PROC SQL statements are executed immediately; The RUN statement has no effect.
```

Answer (score 0):

Potentially this known issue:
https://support.sas.com/kb/57/757.html

See also discussion here:
https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Data-Management/SAS-Error-when-using-quot-delete-from-quot-to-remove-rows-from/td-p/467859

Might be easiest to change to using explicit pass-through.  Something like (untested):

```
proc sql;
  connect using mvt;
  execute by mvt
  (
   delete from Tab1;
  );
quit;
```

With explicit pass-through you write native SQL Server code and the database runs it.  It's generally faster, and you can use native commands like the SQL Server statement `TRUNCATE` which should make it even faster.

Comment: thank you very much, this method works very well, but a bit long, how can I apply TRUNCATE in proc sql?

Comment: The bit in parentheses is SQL Server code, not SAS PROC SQL code.  So you could put `Truncate Table Tab1;` instead of `delete from Tab1;`.  For less typing, you could define a macro as a wrapper, so you could do %truncate(mvt.Tab1) .